# WordPress: Prevent get_query_var() from being cached

Tags: wordpress, caching

I have the below plugin code in PHP:

```
function getHotels() {
    if(get_query_var('htl_destination') !== null) {
        $url = "http://xmlfeed.laterooms.com/index.aspx?aid=100&rtype=4&kword=".get_query_var('htl_destination')."&sdate=".get_query_var('htl_start_date')."&nights=".get_query_var('htl_nights')."";
        $data = file_get_contents($url);

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data) or die("Error cannot create object");
        foreach($xml->hotel as $hotel) {
            echo 
            "<div class='panel'>
                <div>
                    <img class='img-left' src='{$hotel->images}'></img>
                    <div class='price'>
                        <p>Prices from</p>
                        <h1>£".str_replace(".0", "", $hotel->prices_from)."</h1>
                        <a href='#' class='view-now'>View now</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='info'>
                        <h1>{$hotel->hotel_name}</h1>";
                        for($i=0; $hotel->hotel_star > $i; $i++) {
                            echo "<i>&#9733;</i>";
                        }
                        echo "
                        <p>{$hotel->hotel_address}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p>No results</p>";
        print_r($_POST);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input style="margin-left: 0% width: 25%" class="form-control htl_filter" type="text" name="htl_destination" placeholder="Destination" required>
    <input style="margin-left: 0%" class="form-control htl_filter" type="date" name="htl_start_date" placeholder="Date" required>
    <div class="htl_filter" style="margin-left: 0%;">
        <select name="htl_nights" required>
            <option value="1">1 Night</option>
            <?php 
                for ($i=2; $i < 29; $i++) {
                    echo "<option value={$i}>{$i} Nights</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button style="width: 15%;" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted to the following page the query variables are cached so the results go unchanged.

We have the siteground cache plugin installed on our site and the results do not change until I click "Purge SG Cache".

I have tried adding the url of the page which my plugin is on to the siteground cache plugin exclusion list with no success.

Is there a way to stop the variables from being cached?

Comment: If you have a problem with Purge SG Cache, you should ask them for help why the exclusion is not working.

Comment: @Blackbam The problem is not with Purge SG Cache I just added that information to make readers aware that the plugin is installed on the site. Since I've already added the url to the plugin's exclusion list it's very possible that the issue is nothing to do the with that plugin.

Comment: Is htl_destination populated correctly? Because if you do not populate it, obviously it will be empty.

Comment: @Blackbam Yes I have tried printing it and it gives the value that was entered in the form. Sorry I should’ve mentioned the form actually works fine but once someone enters a different destination the code still uses the one they entered previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I tried deactivating the SG cache plugin there was no difference possibly because the web page was being cached by the server. There is however a function which can be called to clear the cache so I've added this into my getHotels() function and the code now works.

The function is

```
if (function_exists('sg_cachepress_purge_cache')) {
    sg_cachepress_purge_cache();
}
```